# Crop video preview of MediaCapture to produce square aspect ratio

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, ms-media-foundation

I'd like to create a video recording app which outputs & previews a 480x480 video that isn't letter-boxed.  This is for windows phone 8.1, but really it should be the same concept for any winRT.

What would be the best way?

Would it be using AddEffectAsync (MFT effect) to do this? Or using a custom sink?

Comment: [`MediaEncodingProfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile.aspx) will help you. Set appropriate profile & then use [`MediaCapture.StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync(MediaEncodingProfile, IMediaExtension)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700855.aspx)

Comment: I'm in full XAML , so I don't need to use custom sink like in SL8.1.  I have set the encoding profile values for width/height, but the video just gets letterboxed not cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Working with MSFT for an answer.  The team has said that the best way to do this is with a MFT.  I'll update this answer with a link to a sample, if I'm allowed to share it.